# Converting values in a dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe loaded from an XLSX file. I want to create another dataframe based on it, but I am unable to do so since every value within a dataframe has a type of *list* (instead of, for instance, *numerical* or *text* as it should be).

I have tried this command to convert all numbers (type: *list*) in the database into numerical values:

```
d[, 3:5] <- lapply(d[, 3:5], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(unlist(x))))
```

However, it is not working. The start of reproducible example with `dput()` looks like the following:

```
structure(list(`age` = c("19", "20", "20", "41", 
"21", "50", "19", "19", "20", "18", "19", "18", "18", "19", "19"...
```

and the end looks like:

```
class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Please let me know how could I possibly convert values in my dataframe from *list* to *numerical* and *character*.

Comment: Your structure is not complete, but it is just a data.frame/tibble.  You may need `library(dplyr);d <- d %>% mutate(across(3:5, ~ as.numeric(.x)))`

Comment: FYI, the whole point of using `dput` is so that we have a **complete** and **usable** (and unambiguous) data structure. What you've provided hints at unambiguous but is far from complete and/or usable. If you want to subset it so that it is not huge, then subset it before dput, as in `dput(head(df[,3:5]))` or such.

Comment: ... and based on your use of `as.numeric(as.character` (suggesting you believe you have `factor`s in your data), I think @akrun's suggestion should really be `d <- d %>% mutate(across(3:5, ~ as.numeric(as.character(.))))`. (For validation, compare `mutate(data.frame(a=factor("11")), across(a, ~as.numeric(.)))` with `mutate(data.frame(a=factor("11")), across(a, ~as.numeric(as.character(.))))`.)